# How to delete one/multiple row/s in two tables based on one table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables (to make things easier I will copy everything here)
that I need to delete from.

The main table to delete from is done based on another table, which this I could do as below

```
select 
    items.item, items.ORDERNO, items.LU_ON, 
    stock.NUMBER, stock.CUSTOMTEXT, stock.LU_ON
from 
    items, stock
where 
    items.item = stock.NUMBER 
    and items.LU_ON >= '2021-11-10' 
    and convert(VARCHAR, STOCK.CUSTOMTEXT) = 'breakout' 
    and convert(VARCHAR, ORDERNO) <> '' 

delete from items
where items.item in (select stock.number 
                     from stock 
                     where items.item = stock.NUMBER 
                       and items.LU_ON >= '2021-11-10' 
                       and convert(VARCHAR, ORDERNO) <> '' 
                       and convert(VARCHAR, STOCK.CUSTOMTEXT) = 'breakout')
```

However in order for this to fully work in SQL without touching the program on the front end i also need to delete the box (from the item which was deleted) from the box table based on the single item in the order which was deleted in the items table. Below are some columns/rows in the items table, i need to delete the first item, and that is based on this item being in the "stock" table which has the 'item' from the items table, just in the stock table 'item' is 'number' and i will delete from the items table any time the lu_on column (in both the stock and items table) has the date which i put in, and also has the word 'breakout' in the 'customtext' column from the stock table.

```
ORDERNO    ITEM_ID   ITEM
-------------------------------
1225971    4208453   HRE-IK.S
1225971    4208454   HRE-IK.B1
1225971    4208455   HRE-IK.B2
```

and below is the main columns of the 'box' table which i need to delete the row which is affected by me deleting it in the items table (this is the part i got stuck)

```
BOX_ID    ORDERNO   BOX   BOXOF
-------------------------------
1027766   1225971    1      1
1027767   1225971    1      2
1027768   1225971    2      2
```

Below is the query i tried to find the correct items, and this query either showed no results, or too many that i don't need (as i am trying to sort only by date)

```
select 
    items.item, items.ORDERNO, items.LU_ON, 
    stock.NUMBER, stock.CUSTOMTEXT, stock.LU_ON,
    box.orderno, box.LU_ON, box.BOX_ID, box.box
from 
    BOX, items, STOCK
where 
    box.boxof not in (select ORDERNO from items) 
    and items.item = stock.NUMBER 
    and box.LU_ON >= '2021-11-10' 
    and items.LU_ON >= '2021-11-10' 
    and convert(VARCHAR, STOCK.CUSTOMTEXT) = 'breakout' 
    and convert(VARCHAR, items.ORDERNO) <> ''
```

So with this too much info shows up, not sure how to isolate what I am looking for, also then i will need to delete what I found, once i know it is correct.

I hope my question was clear enough, it is my first time asking here, and would be happy to clarify/ take pointers.

Thank you!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Another bad habit here is those converts. You are converting to varchar but you don't specify the scale. This means it uses the default scale. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: Thank you, the problem is i guess i don't really know how to troubleshoot joins so well as i always come up with some sort of Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: It would be useful if you paste sample data and expected result, so we can execute the query. This way I am sure we could help you.

Comment: how can i paste the data here in a way that will be legible?

Comment: The absolute best way to share data is by sharing create table statements and then insert statements to populate those tables.

Comment: Thank you, how do i post that here, as it appears to be too long for the comment...